# How to upgrade react-native-firebase version from v3 to v5

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm new to react-native. I need help to upgrade react-native-firebase version from v3 to v5 steps I need to follow. I'm not able to get proper documentation from react-native-firebase. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to update your rn-firebase npm package.

`$ npm i --save react-native-firebase@latest`

Then you need to check if you can still build you app. If not, follow theses steps:

Unlink react-native-firebase using this command:
`$ react-native unlink react-native-firebase`
Then you need to relink it:
`$ react-native link react-native-fireabase`

Then you can look at the documentation and follow the installation steps.
Some of theses steps have already been implemented in your project. APIs didn't change a lot, so it should be pretty quick to make your app run again.